# Using use-State hook in react function always throws an error + How to share a variable with another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm a beginner to programming in Javascript/Typescript and just about to develop my very first app in react. To get some data from the backend (FastAPI) I created the function "GetData" that is executed whenever the button is clicked.

Component 1: Button
import { GetData } from "./socket"

```
export default function Button() {
    return (
        <button onClick={GetData}>
            Run
        </button>
    )
}
```

Component 2 (named socket): websocket and data logic

```
import {useState, createContext} from 'react';

let socket: any;

export async function ConnectWebsocket() {
    socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/");

    socket.onopen = () => {
        console.log('connected')
    }

    socket.onclose = () => {
        console.log('closed')
    }

    socket.onerror = () => {
        console.log('error')
    }
}

export async function GetData() {
    const [data, setData] = useState({});
    
    socket.send("get Data");
    
    socket.onmessage = (event: any) => {
        const newData = JSON.parse(event.data);
        console.log(`Data from server: ${newData}`);
        setData((data) => ({ ...data, ...newData }));
    }

    console.log(`Overall data: ${data}`);
}
```

The problem I'm facing is the useState hook. Whenever I try to stream the data via the websocket by clicking the Run-Button I always get the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
>    See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

I also created a small example using useState-hook and this one worked. Can you spot what I messed up in my code above?

Plus I have another beginner question. How would you make the "data" variable available to a third component (e.g. a table)?

Comment: Take a look on this: [Hooks rules](http://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

Comment: `GetData` isn't a React component nor is it a custom React hook, `useState` can't be used there. What exactly are you wanting to get in response to clicking a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use react hooks inside the actually react component. In your case your Button component. So I would do something like this instead:

```
   class SocketHelper {
    socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/");

    constructor() {
        
        socket.onopen = () => {
            console.log('connected')
        }

        socket.onclose = () => {
            console.log('closed')
        }

        socket.onerror = () => {
            console.log('error')
        }
    }
}

export const socketHelper = new SocketHelper();


export default function Button() {
    const [data, setData] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {

        socketHelper.socket.onmessage = (event: any) => {
            const newData = JSON.parse(event.data);
            console.log(`Data from server: ${newData}`);
            setData((data) => ({ ...data, ...newData }));
        }
    }, []);

    const getData = () => {
        socketHelper.socket.emit("getdata");
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={getData}>
                Run
            </button>
            <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Also you are using socket.send but it doesn't seems like your are using the returned socket. So instead i would use the emit function: https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/#socketemiteventname-args

Comment: thanks, your solution really helped to improve my understanding of hook usage.